# if the divergence of a plane vector field is of fixed sign in an annular region, then the differential equation has at most one periodic orbit in S

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This from Exercise 1.200 in Chicone's Ordinary Differential Equations with Applications.

"Prove: If the divergence of a plane vector field is of fixed sign in an annular region S of the plane, then the associated differential equation has at most one periodic orbit in S"

I felt like I should use some sort of the Green's Theorem or Divergence Theorem related technique, but I'm not quite sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that there exists more than one periodic orbit for the system $\dot x=f(x)$ inside the annular region. Choose two of them. Then these two form the boundary $C$ of a region $D$ contained inside the annular region. Thus, we can apply the divergence form of Green's Theorem: $$\iint_D\nabla\cdot f(x)\,dA=\oint_C f(x)\cdot \hat n\, ds,$$ where $\hat n$ is the unit vector normal to $C$. On periodic orbits, $f(x)\cdot\hat n\equiv 0$, so we would have $\iint_D\nabla\cdot f(x)\,dA=0$. But if $\nabla\cdot f(x)$ has a constant sign, this cannot be true. Thus, there can exist only a single periodic orbit.